# how to convert base64 value into Hexa decimal String and Send that hexa decimal String to Server by using volley in Java android

Tags: java, android, android-volley

how to convert a base64 String into HexaDecimal String and Upload to the server Of HexaDecimal String with adding headers in Volley Library in Java. what are the steps needed to upload hexadecimal string into server in volley  Thanks in Adavance

I tried with base64 String and HexaDecimal(hardcode string) to upload image to server  in Volley , but unfortunately it is not stored Hexadecimal string in Server(SAP OData) , so added the base64 String in getParams method. what is the problem and why it is not uploaded base64 String/ HexaDecimal String.    another issue is how to convert Base64 string into Hexadecimal String in java android .

Comment: Why is it necessary to convert from Base64 to the less efficient hex representation?

Comment: `public static String sixtyFourToHex(String s64) { return HexFormat.of().formatHex(Base64.getDecoder().decode(s64)); }`

Comment: @g00se That code you have posted requires API 34. Or is it also provided by some compatibility library?

Comment: It's Java 17 actually

Comment: Or `String hex = new BigInteger(1, Base64.getDecoder().decode(b64)).toString(16);
`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.